# GeoSPARQL: inferring distance

Tags: sparql, distance, jena, fuseki, geosparql

Is it possible to create using RDF a relationship between points (Latitude/Longitude) such that when loaded into a store (such as Jena Fuseki with the GeoSPARQL extension) that the distance between points will be inferred, e.g. in kilometers?

Otherwise, in order to determine the distance between points and add it to the triple store, I imagine that a query would be necessary for each point (and/or a query with a subquery to essentially to run a query for all points in a single query). Does this sound correct?

Ideally, the solution is fast as there could be millions of points. For example, I tried measuring 600,000 points to 9,000 linestrings (600k x 9k comparisons) in Jena GeoSPARL Fuseki and each comparison was taking roughly 10 seconds.

Comment: it takes 10s per comparison? Are you sure? This would mean your test would have taken `600,000 * 9,000 = 5,400,000,000` comparisons times 10s which means `1 711.19329 years`

Comment: why would you want to store 5 billion triples in the dataset just for the distance? This is rather inefficient in my opinion. The Jena Geospatial index already takes care of efficiently storing the geometries, computing the distance at query time should be sufficient. Indeed not if you really do a pairwise computations between all geometries, then feel free to store the result as triples (5 billion is already considered large by the way) with a SPARQL Update query.

Comment: I'm not sure if the generic rule based reasoner would take care of the geospatial extension, you would have to try it out. But doing a SPARQL Update statement sounds easier to me

Comment: @UninformedUser Unfortunately, the query takes 10 seconds for one point/line comparison. I suppose my question was just to find out if there were alternatives to using a SPARQL query to get the resulting distances. The problem is about finding closest points, so it seems the best approach now is to manually deselect some of the obviously far points (reduce 600k), as well as coalesce some lines into regions (reduce 9k).

Comment: @UninformedUser Sorry that's 10 seconds to count the number of points within a given distance to any given line, e.g. within 1 KM of a line. So that would be 9k x 10s, or roughly 25 hours.

Comment: so for each point it takes ~ 10s to compute the distances to all 9k lines? hm, not sure if there is room for optimization - the Jena geospatial index already stores all geometries into some optimized datastructure (technically either quad or r tree, details are here: https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/index/strtree/STRtree.html)

Comment: so your use case is to find the closest points to a given set of lines? I'm interested, how big is the spatial index file?

Comment: Here are also some maybe too technical benchmarks, but I'm interesed as well in perfomance of geospatial libs now: [current libs evaluation](http://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1600467/1600467.pdf) (Jena is using JTS) and here a [GeoSPARQL benchmark](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~koubarak/publications/2021/Geographica2-long.pdf)

Comment: @UninformedUser spatial.index is 55MB. At least 10s in the best case after an initial search (cached?). Somewhere around 30-40s more likely. And yes that's one point against 9k lines. I think the best optimization may be creating a clustering, for both lines and points, and then using those before doing any actual distance search. But it also turns out perhaps 50% of the data isn't going to be useful and can be discarded. Just would be helpful to use a distance query to delete. But there's other ways to get rid of it of course.